# I am trying to create an android wear watch face. but i am getting an error i can't solve

Tags: android, wear-os, watch-face-api

```
Resources resources = MyWatchFace.this.getResources();
        Drawable backgroundDrawable= resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.face1, null);
        mBackgroundBitmap=((BitmapDrawable)backgroundDrawable).getBitmap();
```

I am getting an error when I run the watch face on the emulator, I mean, the watch face runs but in the log file i have an error :

> "06-20 18:56:12.025    7540-7548/? E/art﹕ Failed writing handshake
>   bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe".

And also the background of the watch face that i am trying to mount, it doesn't scale correctly, I would have uploaded an image, but i need to have at least 10 rep.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/qfb6po94l/  , and also the seconds tick leaves a mark in the background, those white stripes